# How to rotate 180 degrees an mtext() in R

Tags: r, plot

Apparently, `mtext()` in R doesn't support the `srt` parameter whose job is to **rotate a piece of text**.

I need `mtext()` to create an **axis title on side 4** of my ***moving*** plot (i.e., **values to be plotted come from a function so they change and so do the plot axes values**). I was wondering then, what options do I have to ***rotate 180 degrees*** this **side 4 axis title?**

An **example is BELOW:**

```
curve(dnorm(x),-3,3)
mtext("Strength",side=4,srt=180)
```

Comment: I know las=2 will give you a horizontal text.

Comment: You could also switch to `text`. In `?par`, the `srt` documentation says "Only supported by `text`"...

Comment: I've not done it before but I think you can use `convertXY` to find out what user coordinates are needed for a certain device coordinate or normalized device coordinate input.

Comment: Whoops, that's the help page name, `graphics::grconvertX` and similar for Y. [documentation link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/convertXY.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `par("usr")` to obtain extremes of the plot area and use it to place your `text` without having to explicitly specify the `x` and `y`.

Try

```
curve(dnorm(x),-3,3)
corners = par("usr") #Gets the four corners of plot area (x1, x2, y1, y2)
par(xpd = TRUE) #Draw outside plot area
text(x = corners[2]+.5, y = mean(corners[3:4]), "Strength", srt = 270)
```

This way it will always be on the right extreme and vertically in the middle.

Comment: A fair point, though this is not always possible, for example if multiple plots are output by a single function.